# Как отправить запрос на сервер в виде json

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, json, api

Всех приветствую не давно начал изучать js и хочу сделать авторизацию по api, запрос отправляю через ajax (Jquery) но на сервере вижу `log=admin&pass=passs` вместо ожидаемого `{log:admin, pass:passs}` в гугле толкого ничего нет везде пишут как получить от сервера json и распарсить его.

код js:

```
function push(login,password){
    $.ajax({
    type: "POST",
    url: "http://localhost/status",
    cahce: false,
    contentType:"application/json; charset=UTF-8; application/x-www-form-urlencoded",
    dataType: "json",
    data: {"log":"admin", "pass":"passs"},
    success: function(result){
        console.log(result)
    }
});}
function input_v(){
    log = document.getElementById("login").value;
    pass =  document.getElementById("password").value;
    push(log,pass)
}
```

html :

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <title>Document</title>
    <script src="js/jquery.js"></script>
    <script src="js/script.js"></script>
</head>
<body>
    <form name="login_f" id=form>
        <h3>login</h3>
        <input type="text" id="login" name="login">
        <br><h3>pass</h3>
        <input type="passwords" id="password" name="password">
        <input type="button" id="btn" value="Enter" onclick="input_v()">
    </form>
</body>
</html>
```

[image]

Comment: Ну Вы уж определитесь `contentType` у Вас должен быть `"application/json;"` или `"application/x-www-form-urlencoded"`, а то указано и то и то.

Comment: `data: JSON.stringify(...)`. Ну либо переходить на axios или fetch. Там json из коробки отправляется

Answer (score 0):

У тебя стоит application/x-www-form-urlencoded, от приводит к такому результату

Comment: все равно так выводит ((

Answer (score 0):

Достаточно и так:

```
function Input_v(){
let log = $("#login").val(),
    pass =  $("#password").val();

Push(log,pass);
}

function Push((login,password) => $.post('test.php', 
{log:login,pas:password});
```